# JavaScript_calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: Sorry for the confusing question on the first try.

What i want to create is a calculator with JavasScript and jQuery.
The calculator should include:

- 2 basic fields for numbers
- a selection of the operations "+ , - , * , / "
- a button to calculate the numbers entered
- a button which creates more fields for numbers

This arbitrary number of fields is then to be calculated with the one selected operation.
In my code I have tried to take all of these things into account and incorporate them, but unfortunately this does not work. Nothing happens with the calculate and "+ Add" button.
Furthermore, an alert should come if something other than a number is entered in the fields. I know that you can do this via NaN, but not how to build it in accordingly. I hope somebody can help with his. And again sorry for the confusing question on the first try.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8" >
    <meta name = "Calculator" content = "simple calculator with JavaScript" >
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<table class= "table table-bordered" id="simple_calculator">
<tr><td><input type="text" id="value1" placeholder="Number"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="valueX" placeholder="Number"></td>

<td><button name="add" id="add">+add</button></td><br/>
</tr></table>    
    <select id="operator">
        <option value="add">+</option>
        <option value="min">-</option>
        <option value="div">/</option>
        <option value="mul">*</option>
    </select>

    <button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document.readyState(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function(){  
        i++;  
        $('#simple_calculator').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" id="valueX" placeholder="Number"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');    
   });  
   $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
   }); 
},
function calc() {
    var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("value1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("valueX").value);
    var op = document.querySelector("operator").value;
    var calculate;

    if (op =="add") {
        calculate = a + b;
    }
    else if (op == "min") {
        calculate = a - b;
    } else if (op == "div") {
        calculate = a / b;
    } else if (op == "mul"){
        calculate = a * b
    }

document.querySelector("result")
}))
```

Comment: I would recommend posting any code you have so far. It works much better if people can help adjust code you already have, rather than asking others to write code from scratch. Regardless, yes, this is possible - you can easily add new inputs to a form using appendChild. Here's more info: http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/02/add-input-fields-dynamically-to-form-using-javascript.html

Comment: @Zerowiel While the question does need some improvement, your answer does not provide any help. First of all like you said yourself it is React, while the tags say JS and JQuery. Also the little things that are clear on the question are that the use of multiple fields is required.

Comment: ***"any number of fields"***? What are you considering a field? A DOM Element? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Question is a bit too abstract as written. Show us what you mean

Answer (score -2):

The way your question is asked it leaves a lot of for interpretation and it is best that you update your answer with what you have and maybe a sketch of how you see what you need.

To solve the first issue with the different fields you can use class attribute. You can give every input field a class like this:

```
<input type="number" class="valueField" />
```

And search on it with

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("valueField");
```

Comment: The javascript code is incorrect! It should be `var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("valueField");`